# pop.size argument in GenMatch() respectively genoud()

Tags: r, genetic-algorithm

I am using genetic matching in R using `GenMatch` in order to find comparable treatment and control groups to estimate a treatment effect. The default code for matching looks as follows:

```
GenMatch(Tr, X, BalanceMatrix=X, estimand="ATT", M=1, weights=NULL,
         pop.size = 100, max.generations=100,...)
```

The description for the `pop.size` argument in the package is:

> Population Size. This is the number of individuals genoud uses to
>   solve the optimization problem. The theorems proving that genetic
>   algorithms find good solutions are asymptotic in population size.
>   Therefore, it is important that this value not be small. See genoud
>   for more details.

Looking at `gnoud` the additional description is:

> ...There are several restrictions on what the value of this number can
>   be. No matter what population size the user requests, the number is
>   automatically adjusted to make certain that the relevant restrictions
>   are satisfied. These restrictions originate in what is required by
>   several of the operators. In particular, operators 6 (Simple
>   Crossover) and 8 (Heuristic Crossover) require an even number of
>   individuals to work on—i.e., they require two parents. Therefore, the
>   pop.size variable and the operators sets must be such that these three
>   operators have an even number of individuals to work with. If this
>   does not occur, the population size is automatically increased until
>   this constraint is satisfied.

I want to know how `gnoud` (resp. `GenMatch`) incorporates the population size argument. Does the algorithm randomly select *n* individuals from the population for the optimization?

I had a look at the package description and the source code, but did not find a clear answer.

Comment: Have the same issue. I noticed that the results even keep changing when pop.size is set to be larger than the total sample

Answer (score 2):

The word "individuals" here does not refer to individuals in the sample (i.e., individual units your dataset), but rather to virtual individuals that the genetic algorithm uses. These individuals are individual draws of a set of the variables to be optimized. They are unrelated to your sample.

The goal of genetic matching is to choose a set of scaling factors (which the `Matching` documentation calls weights), one for each covariate, that weight the importance of that covariate in a scaled Euclidean distance match. I'm no expert on the genetic algorithm, but my understanding of what it does is that it makes a bunch of guesses at the optimal values of these scaling factors, keeps the ones that "do the best" in the sense of optimizing the criterion (which is determined by `fit.func` in `GenMatch()`), and creates new guesses as slight perturbations of the kept guesses. It then repeats this process many times, simulating what natural selection does to optimize traits in living things. Each guess is what the word "individual" refers to in the description for `pop.size`, which corresponds to the number of guesses at each generation of the algorithm.

`GenMatch()` always uses your entire sample (unless you have provided a restriction like a caliper, exact matching requirement, or common support rule); it does not sample units from your sample to form each guess (which is what bagging in is other machine learning contexts).

Results will change over many runs because the genetic algorithm itself is a stochastic process. It may converge to a solution asymptotically, but because it is optimizing over a lumpy surface, it will find different solutions each time in finite samples with finite generations and a finite population size (i.e., `pop.size`).